# Is there anything wrong with this approach to proving the Fundamental Theorem of Algebra?

Tags: abstract-algebra, polynomials

Consider every possible quadratic and every possible polynomial of degree $ 2n $ (both monic with real coefficients). Their product is
$$(x^2+ax+b)(x^{2n}+c_{2n-1}x^{2n-1}+...+c_0)=x^{2n+2}+(a+c_{2n-1})x^{2n+1}+...+c_0b$$
Fixing $c_{2n-1}$ in the order $2n-1$ term,  $c_{2n-2}$ in the order $2n-2$ term, etc. then fixing $a$ in the order $1$ term and $b$ in the order $0$ term gives every possible monic polynomial of degree $2n+2$. This implies every possible polynomial of degree $2n+2$ can be written as a product of a quadratic and a polynomial of degree $2n$. By induction, this implies every even degree polynomial may be written as a product of quadratics. Since every quadratic polynomial factors uniquely into linear factors over $\mathbb{C}$, this implies every even degree polynomial factors into unique linear factors over $\mathbb{C}$, and therefore its degree equals its number of roots.

This proof seems too simple to me. Harsh criticism is appreciated! Thanks.

Comment: As you're putting it, it seems quite simplistic. How does this come to fruition for the factorization of $x^6+x^5+x^4+x^3+x^2+x+1$?

Comment: "This implies every possible polynomial of degree $2n+2$ can be written as a product of a quadratic and a polynomial of degree $2n$." Why?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

First of all, the statement you are trying to prove is not the Fundamental Theorem of Algebra (FTA): You are trying to prove that every $f\in\mathbb R[x]$ has $\deg(f)$ roots in $\mathbb C$ (you are only considering polynomials with $\deg(f)$ even, but it is easy to reduce polynomials with odd degree to those with even degree), while the FTA states that every **complex** polynomial $f\in\mathbb C[x]$ has a root in $\mathbb C$.

Second, in your equation you are missing the terms for $x^{2n}$ and $x^{2n+1}$, your coefficient of $x^{2n-1}$ is wrong as well.

Third, you do not give a valid proof for your statement

> every possible polynomial of degree $2n+2$ can be written as a product of a quadratic and a polynomial of degree $2n$.

If you pick $f=x^{2n+2}+\sum_{k=0}^{2n+1}\lambda_kx^k\in\mathbb R[x]$, you would need to show (with your notation for the quadratic and the polynomial of degree $2n$), that the following system of equations has a solution \begin{align*}\lambda_{2n+1}&=a+c_{2n-1}\\\lambda_{2n}&=c_{2n-2}+ac_{2n-1}+bc_{2n}\\&\ \ \vdots\\\lambda_0&=c_0b\end{align*} for all possible choices of $\lambda_i$ and it is not at all obvious that this system of non-linear equations has a solution in the real numbers.